# Is it possible to use C++ CFX tags in Railo?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

I recently had to move several older websites that were running in Coldfusion MX7 onto a server running Railo 4.2.1. These sites all use either CFX_Image or CFX_OpenImage tags for resizing uploaded images. It looks like I could rewrite them all to use CFIMAGE, but I'm hoping to get these older sites working as is, at least for know.

Does anyone know of a way to use the C++ CFX tags in Railo 4.2.1?

Comment: What operations are these CFX tags performing?  Could you post samples in case that the optimizations don't exist in CFImage. (CFX_OpenImage has some functions & conversion support that isn't available in CFImage.)

Comment: For CFX_Image, we're just doing simple resizing. The CFX-OpenImage tag is being used to resize and reproportion images by added extra white space if necessary.

Comment: Using ColdFusion, I've found CFImage to be slow and prefer the CFX tags. I have no experience with the Railo performance.  I'd recommend taking a couple of original uploaded files and check out imageUtils() AspectCrop http://imageutils.riaforge.org/ (or you'll need to use java to create an empty white canvas & center a cropped image on top.)

Comment: Well, my first choice for now anyway, is to use the CFX tags if I can get them to work in Railo. I'd rather not have to rewrite these using CFImage right now.

Comment: I had to deal with a couple of 32bit CFX tags (CSVtoQuery & ISOCalendar) that weren't compatible w/64bit... I wrote CF-based custom tags w/parameters that mimicked the CFX tag. I then updated references to the CFX tag by changing the prefix to "CF".  It looks like C++ CFX tags are in the roadmap http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/railo-roadmap/roadmap-history/ and can be enabled via the admin http://www.getrailo.org/index.cfm/documentation/cfadmin-doc/ but there's not really much information regarding it.

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is not an issue them not running because of 32 vs 64 bit. I also plan on using CFImage in the future. I just want to get this batch of older sites functioning again in Railo until we have time to upgrade more than just their image processing.

Comment: Did you search the Railo list ie http://groups.google.com/d/forum/railo ? A [few threads](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/ivmXXvqbvZI) suggest some have gotten it working - to what extent (and with which versions) - I do not know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Railo 4.2 is supposed to be compatible with CF 10 but it doesn't support C++ tags. It's intended to be compatible as far as cfml syntax goes but
there are however a few things railo doesn't support, c++ cfx tags being one of them. It does support Java CFX tags. [Read this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/railo/7yhueUiryI8)

But you can always use `cfimage` tag to perform various image manipulation operations including image resizing. Like this

```
<cfimage 
    action = "resize" 
    height = "number of pixels|percent%" 
    source = "absolute pathname|pathname relative to the web root|URL|#cfimage variable#" 
    width = "number of pixels|percent%" 
    destination = "absolute pathname|pathname relative to the web root" 
    isBase64 = "yes|no" 
    name = "cfimage variable" 
    overwrite = "yes|no">
```

Comment: Thanks Pankaj. In following the link you sent, I found someone posting about C++ support being a hidden feature in the CFX tags section. It looks like it's in beta and they don't make it available unless you know exactly how to activate it. I will try out the suggestions in that post.